# Population inversion requirement for multiexcitonic lasing

Tags: laser, nanoscience, collective-excitations

I am working with optically active nanomaterials ([quantum dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dot), [perovskites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perovskite_nanocrystal)), that have pretty large [exciton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exciton) binding energies and can form multiexcitonic complexes, e.g. biexcitons, relatively easily. It has been well established that they also exhibit biexcitonic lasing/ASE under above threshold excitation, so here I have a question.

To have lasing behavior/ASE, stimulated emission process should occur which requires population inversion between upper (biexciton) and lower (exciton) states.

However, in the current literature when this effect is reported for any new material, population inversion requirement is barely ever mentioned and I wonder why. Is it for some reason biexcitonic recombination is a "special" transition, and therefore this requirement is lifted, or population inversion indeed takes place?

If any of these options is correct, could you, please, elaborate why that happens? What is the mechanism lasing or inversion build-up?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The [The RP Photonics Encyclopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html) is a good place to start. For example, see the article on [Population Inversion](https://www.rp-photonics.com/population_inversion.html).

Comment: Thanks @mmesser314 , that is helpful!